# Converting incomplete string to a date in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I've got a list of data with timestamps that are missing years, the purpose of the data is for forecasting, so we'll just tack on the year going forward, but how can I store these strings as dates?

They follow the following format:

`01 Jan`

`02 Jan`

...

`31 Jan`

I thought SQL would automatically convert them, with the minimum year and time, but its throwing a conversion failed error. Any ideas? I'm not an sql guy, so I'm stumped.

*more info*

I have a requirement to store these in an existing table, one that has a datetime column for timestamps, otherwise I would simply store these as strings and do the conversion in the UI.

Comment: What year do you want to give it?

Comment: What is your front end?  Why don't you use it to tack on a space and the current year?

Comment: Try this - `select CAST('01 Jan ' + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) As datetime)`

Comment: That did the trick, rs, thanks! Post an answer for the rep.

Comment: Is this something that is one time (like next year which would necessitate a dynamic year be set or reoccurring?   if one time there's a fair amount of unneeded overhead above, you could just `SELECT CAST('01 Jan ' & '2013' as datetime)`

Comment: @xQbert, there is no `&` operator for string concatenation in sql server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this

```
select CAST('01 Jan ' + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) As datetime)
```

or

```
select CAST(columnname + ' ' + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) As datetime)
FROm TableName
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CAST(Field + ' ' + CAST(Year(GetDate()) AS Varchar) AS DateTime)
FROM YourTable
```

And the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d1095/1).

Good luck.